# Topological features (and / or definition) of homology

Tags: general-topology

I am coming to grips with basic homological algebra as of late, in order to better understand my own subject, that of the study of language. The thing is, I have recently read in some handbook that Aleksandrov provided topological definitions for some (no idea if all) concepts from homological algebra. Specifically, I would like to know if (and how) he defines homology, (bounded) chain complex, tensor product and, eventually, quiver, from a topological point of view.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Honestly, you would need to read a textbook, or take a course, in algebraic topology. There are dozens of books and I am sure there are plenty of questions on the site asking for recommendations for books on algebraic topology. Some texts are more focused on homology, some less, but it is one of the fundamental tools in the subject.